# Android App apk size vs. install size and how to decrease them?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have published an app a few days ago which contains a lot of image but all of them are stored in firebase. What ı do not understand is apk size is 3.4 mb but when ı try to install the app from playstore ıt needs 108 mb. I want to know how to decrease this amount and ı really do not understand how ıt needs 108 mb since it has no image and it is not big project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method to decrease the apk size, you need to go to the build.gradle file and find a line that looks like that:

```
minifyEnabled false;
```

Change it to "true".

Add this line of code under:

```
shrinkResources = true
```

If you want to know more about this, see this Android Studio link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Also, to reduce more the apk size, upload your application as apk bundle to the play store, this will compress more the app.